# WCF client - The EncryptedKey clause was not wrapped with the required encryption token

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services, ssl

We need to consume a DataPower webservice running SSL and WS-Security.

I have setup a WCF web service running HTTP and custom username password authentication, to be accessed within our network. This web service is consumed from our Oracle database(Oracle cannot do direct connections with WS-Security).

When our local web service is invoked, it makes the call to the external web service, adding in all the WS-Security headers and certificates.

The external web service requires certificate authentication on Transport, and x509 certificates for singing and encrypting the message.

I have setup a CustomBinding in the client app.config (web service is self-hosted as a windows service) and am able to make a connection to the external web service. The guys that maintain the external web service say they are receiving my messages successfully, processing the data and sending the response.

The problem is when my client tries to process the response, I get a "The EncryptedKey clause was not wrapped with the required encryption token 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken'." error.

With the WCF logging, I can see the message I receive, and see the HTTP OK status.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web><compilation debug="true" /></system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxx.fff.eee/Service"
        behaviorConfiguration="WSSecBehavior" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Soap11_Secure" contract="xxx.yyy"
        name="ddddddd" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TEST_Service_Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Test_Proxy.PasswordValidator, Test_Proxy" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WSSecBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                               storeName="TrustedPeople"
                               x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"
                               findValue="dfgasdfgsdgsgfds" />
            <issuedToken defaultKeyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" cacheIssuedTokens="True" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"  />
              <scopedCertificates > 
                <add targetUri="https://xxx.fff.eee/Service" 
                     storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                      storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="sdfgsdfgsdfgsfdg"  />
             </scopedCertificates>
              <defaultCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                      storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg"  />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="TEST_Service_Behavior" name="Test_Proxy.TEST_Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soap11Binding"
          name="Soap11" bindingName="Soap11" contract="Test_Proxy.ITEST_Service" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8449/GCOS_WebService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="soap11Binding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="Soap11_Secure">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Rsa15" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="False"
            enableUnsecuredResponse="false" authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
            messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
            securityHeaderLayout="Strict" requireDerivedKeys="False">
          </security>
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" authenticationScheme="Negotiate"
            maxBufferSize="5000000" requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
<diagnostics performanceCounters="All" wmiProviderEnabled="True">
  <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="True"
       logMalformedMessages="True"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="True"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="True"
       maxMessagesToLog="5000"
       maxSizeOfMessageToLog="50000" logKnownPii="True"/>
</diagnostics>  
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
<system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="true"/>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="sharedListener"
       type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
       initializeData="Test_Service_Proxy.svclog" />
</sharedListeners>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing" >
    <listeners>
      <add name="sharedListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose"  >
    <listeners>
      <add name="sharedListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Any help or direction please.

Request sent:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-1717e10e-8265-4ada-9dee-d01782ed03a9-1">
                <u:Created>2013-10-27T18:14:45.248Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2013-10-27T18:19:45.248Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:BinarySecurityToken>
                <!-- Removed-->
            </o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">5ldE9AdwhGZ/xckWL9rimuji1eY=</o:KeyIdentifier>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
                <e:CipherData>
                    <e:CipherValue>HPG3N2VwCSqS3ImLrKLzodnK/I23oPFk097vp8Iru2ZVmR7EotdnL9tU61C6/b8fUU36ntkDVnsECdp0nYqSSbgu9Hoo6LUIEXVLEySqjcj7M3YNeutHwuY1SK5FKdcfFcTuT7a5drxXHzkpJAEyiW7PAxF4c7BF/iVNYXhgcm0lZDpAct2cGhzdSx6gq+K4SMUVq44Vg6Z89yUVyQsERN3nY++DuJC4yn0Z718fD1+tiNlNXNuX2d1JAP1kh9UO0sYIb06lgg5lXmHAzU2XC5MFcPoK6w0HmKH3cyVThFDfnCMeB//xtVcUS7lgDo81o6YF2sstpH+aLHUemuhQTg==</e:CipherValue>
                </e:CipherData>
            </e:EncryptedKey>
            <c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_1" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
                <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <o:Reference URI="#_0"/>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
                <c:Length>16</c:Length>
                <c:Nonce>
                    <!-- Removed-->
                </c:Nonce>
            </c:DerivedKeyToken>
            <e:ReferenceList xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:DataReference URI="#_3"/>
            </e:ReferenceList>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_2">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>eBkrZ4r7IEHLDZANylfLVRCNnrc=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#uuid-1717e10e-8265-4ada-9dee-d01782ed03a9-1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>EqW8YFzg8XMFLjUNfDlxY6fQR5k=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>CGzogpiUa6jTUmLdd9EiqQdd7VeV3naM59raFqjtjtEf5pPk1a4uwk0ihuzWR7RZTXCa+oieqEE/oEQgEdXzjvDxXUUrmEcIV+be5HSBRw0GPj52Cp55kBHV5hfOCUfsmXcgGQ2mxFNyFQchbKQ20sAGgse+z/GzLnkFnGy/RWQ=</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-1bb3eb61-bd9e-42a9-9d0d-81de76cbbe73-3"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body u:Id="_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <e:EncryptedData Id="_3" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#_1"/>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
            <e:CipherData>
                <e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
            </e:CipherData>
        </e:EncryptedData>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Response Received:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
                <dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">y1cWMPtJ5ta+ZXxOOHKhkAwG5zM=</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </dsig:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <xenc:CipherValue>T1TGYnixXqFJcR82RDV9t43jzD6w31zg8uV3Yv84ZG2+wXms2ajayviZ9Ps7+ak4nPVd8uP4u/zYl2jLCpCwEquA2mJ13P6guqcLQt4091ndJAjnBv1EljANCUB7sE4+W6VLZ6zZLhU7kzdH8dF1SUiDS4soSv8/hfWjK3OOrS4=</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:ReferenceList>
                    <xenc:DataReference URI="#body"/>
                </xenc:ReferenceList>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-3c6a0000-8873-44a3-a1ce-7020c285baed" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsu:Created>2013-10-27T18:14:55Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2013-10-27T18:19:55Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                <!-- Removed-->
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-9c1b48c4-0bde-48af-9086-f8ce71eb74dd">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>F3pP+zcm2Iq8GewW/A4GX5kK8aU=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Timestamp-3c6a0000-8873-44a3-a1ce-7020c285baed">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>MiDu5ZphIhMIAb9ISBj1EKOIfOY=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>gEjjen88BeWVuTD7t2txOCFXfEOE2g2bvDbWnxS24tSJYpvywl+PEzif5Is/AXTzgmL/McU8/GOgxt8ZKTLe1k3Ux4ZlGCFQiuEyk/1rmEJ1UYt4wn6O0k3PU34HOgCJDjC/0CYjdNFEgG9rwFk6+H8nldCcbI8ZMsM+6OwvECthB5CNgwM3FZcIIZJmTUkEQLEsszw08xaao7kyZCMbs5HBvUr5kNrIiim0pbYO0o5eFF2A59NBfNugo8EYwvC9mkcy8/RJv7aDflxoLxPNgyV7HCFTyt5lwApo1yzOQFVFduGxCyQACBJdR5kevkmfiqBWTYWk6+/YcqaacNXKPg==</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns="">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-1e313a32-f22f-43bf-a2d7-a2a24b98a3ef" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="Id-9c1b48c4-0bde-48af-9086-f8ce71eb74dd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xenc:EncryptedData Id="body" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: hi - please publish a sample working request and response.

Comment: @Yaron, I have updated the question with the request and response messages. As you can see, i get a valid response. Could this issue be related to me using a self-signed certificate, or the certificate being incorrectly created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was certificate related. Once we got a valid certificate with Digital Signature and Key Encipherment, everything started working.

Dont think my self-signed (self-generated) certificate had all the necessary usages.

@Yaron - Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set up a WCF service with the same setting and verify it is working with the client, and then compare the structure of its response to the failing response.

Assuming they are the same structure (otherwise need to change binding) one option is that the response uses an encryption certificate which is different than the one you used to sign with in the request.  Verify that the value inside the response  keyInfo is indeed the subjectKeyIdentifier of the certificate you used to sign with.

```
<wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">y1cWMPtJ5ta+ZXxOOHKhkAwG5zM=</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
```

Comment: what are the certificate properties that are required during a certificate request to be able to sign and encrypt SOAP messages?

Comment: not sure the exact name, standard ssl certificates should work, if that was the problem I think you would get another exception

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue. Turns out it was due generated self-signed certificate without Subject Key Identifier (SKI). Check this answer:

[WCF : The EncryptedKey clause was not wrapped with the required encryption token 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686785/wcf-the-encryptedkey-clause-was-not-wrapped-with-the-required-encryption-token)